# How to switch between global CSS onclick in Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, css, gatsby

I'm building a portfolio site in Gatsby, and as I work more on the illustration and design side, would like to serve up multiple design options to showcase that work, based on a user selection via click. I've found some similar questions, but none that are specific to Gatsby.

I'm using styled components to create the layout, so It seems to me that just swapping between multiple Global stylesheets (with fonts, colors, etc) via a button would be the way to go, so the layout remains intact, but I'm honestly not sure how to go about this as I'm pretty beginner in Gatsby and Javascript in general.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don not gatsby, but an easy way would be to use different classes on the `body` element. Bind the class attribute to some kind of selector (button, select, radio, …). Then you can prepend that class to any CSS selectors you want changed. Does that help get you started?

Comment: I see where you're going there and I could probably get there that way, but for the gatsby/react use case, I think the answer suggested by @Ferran below will be cleaner and help to keep all styles separated by theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a simply `<Layout>` structure like:

```
import React from "react"
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: ${props => (props.theme === "purple" ? "purple" : "white")};
  }
`
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyle theme="purple" />
      {children}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

You can easily attach an `onClick` event to the `children` by adding a boolean operator to switch your `<GlobalStyle>`, for example:

```
export default function somePage(){
   const [defaultStyles, setDefaultStyles]=useState(false);

   const handleChange=()=>setDefaultStyles(!defaultStyles)
   
   return <Layout defaultStyles={defaultStyles}>
      <h1 onClick={handleChange}> Click me to toggle the global styles</h1>
   </Layout>

}
```

Basically, you are creating a boolean state (initially set as `false`) to change between default styles. The result of that state (toggled by clicking the `<h1>`) will be sent upwards to your `<Layout>` so, there:

```
import React from "react"
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: ${props => (props.theme === "purple" ? "purple" : "white")};
  }
`
export default function Layout({ children, defaultStyles }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {defaultStyles && <GlobalStyle theme="purple" />}
      {children}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

The `&&` operator will only render `<GlobalStyle>` if `defaultStyles` is `true`. Adapt it to your needs or add a ternary condition if needed.

Comment: Yes! This could definitely work. I actually just learned about useState() in building a full screen toggle nav menu. It makes perfect sense if I'm only toggling between 2 styles, could I modify if I have 3 or more style options? I'm really only familiar with useState in the toggle/boolean context, but looking at the docs, it appears to be possible?

Comment: Yes, definitely! It always depends on your use-cases and requeriments, but this approach is perfectly doable and scalable